# Google Calendar API Issue?

Tags: php, json, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am needing to use the Google Calendar API to retrieve even data from my calendar.

I created my application and created my server API Key. I entered in my IP address (Since i am running on my test server).

After that, i created my simple PHP file that uses Curl to request data from Google's Servers. The File looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/myCalendarEmail@gmail.com/events?maxResults=15&key={My Key}");
$result=curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

However, when this is executed, i recieve this JSON (Error):

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

I even entered the URL in my browser and got Data. After a couple hours of messing around with it, my browser returns the same error message? Did i miss something, or is this just a bug?

Here is what the API Console gives me (This proves when i said it worked in my browser and not via Curl)

[image]

Comment: Did you make this calendar public? According to [this](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#usingkeys) (and you're using only a API-key) only public information can be retrieved with (just) an API-key. Otherwise you need to use OAuth 2.0. The reason it worked temporarily in the browser could be that you had a cookie set for login. For private calendars you need to use OAuth 2.0 (or you need to make your calendar public).

Comment: @Rik Yes, it is public. I was able to get the feed from the old version.=, but i need this new one to work.

Comment: I take it you checked that myCalendarEmail@gmail.com is indeed the "Calendar ID" of your public calendar? Could you try recreating the "server API key" without entering an "Allowed IP"? (Did you use your external or internal IP? Both didn't work for me. Omitting the IP did work for me, not very secure though, but it's a start:)

Comment: I checked everything. The ID is correct, i have tried re-creating my keys, with and without allowed IP address. I used external IP addresses (as well as their IPV6 address). I have no idea what is wrong with it. @Rik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting two days the API responses started to work. This confuses me very much, and i really expected a more professional API from Google. I will continue to watch this question until someone posts a real fix to this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
2) Select a project.
3) In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the Google Calendar API.

Comment: It is on. I also entered the correct IP addresses for the server as well. Idk what could be wrong.